# Pdf doesn't show all japanese characters

Tags: android, pdf, itext, itextg

I am making a pdf with **iTextg** in android. It works for some Japanese characters but not all. i am using "**arialuni.ttf**" in fonts which is around **1.4mb**. When am using **Arial-unicode-ms (22.4mb)**, things work fine but sze is too much for android app.

**Example:-** "Elephant"- "象" in Japanese  print nothing or "how are you" -"お元気ですか"  prints partial "元ですか".

Any hep will be appreciated.

Comment: add your code so that we can understand your problem

Comment: everything is working fine but some characters in Japanese are not working like "Elephant"- "象" in japanese or "how are you" -"お元気ですか" is not printing. it prints partial "元ですか"

Comment: did you try to open the file in chrome or adobe ? try both and tell me what happened ?

Comment: tried that too. In chrome and other browsers

Comment: Please add your code to your question. Thank you!